# Keep a ToolStripDropDownButton dropped down for multiple selections

Tags: .net, winforms, drop-down-menu

I have a [`ToolStripDropDownButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownbutton.aspx) that has multiple children and I'm using them as checkboxes (`CheckOnClick=True`) so you can check multiple child items.

My question is: **how do I keep the parent item "dropped down" so it doesn't close up every time you click a child item?**

Comment: Show dropdown on parent? Where within the CSS code do you put "ShowDropDown()" Thanks

Comment: Oh, actually it was a WinForms app...so no CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So simple I overlooked it - in the click event handler, just call `ShowDropDown()` on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is prevent the closing of the drop down in the case that an item was clicked:

```
dropDownButton.DropDown.Closing += DropDown_Closing;

private void DropDown_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```